# phpmyadmin displaying ?????? when language field is saved

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi everyone I'm currently using **phpmyadmin** to build a table but I'm having several problems.

These are my current settings:

```
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
Server version: 5.5.16
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4
Perl/v5.10.1
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $
PHP extension: mysql
```

I'm trying to fill the native_name column of my language column.

It has to look sorta like this:

```
Language ID  Language Code  Language name   Native name   Active
-----------  -------------  -------------   ------------  ------
1            afr            Afrikaans       Afrikaans     0
2            sqi            Albanian        gjuha shqipe  1
3            ara            Arabic          العربية
4            spa            Spanish         Espanol       1
5            eng            English         English       1
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
Language ID  Language Code  Language name   Native name   Active
-----------  -------------  -------------   ------------  ------
1            afr            Afrikaans       Afrikaans     0
2            sqi            Albanian        gjuha shqipe  1
3            ara            Arabic          ?????????
4            spa            Spanish         Espanol       1
5            eng            English         English       1
```

[image]

Ok so this is how the story went. As you know from the example above; the native name column has to contain a whole bunch of strange characters. I got the ???? ??? entry while doing the insert via SQL so then I decided that maybe an inline edit would solve things.

After saving my in line edit however the Arabic text I had pasted in reverted back to ??????? ???? on page refresh.

[image]

Any idea on how I can solve this? As you can see its happening on all the characters (i.e. Japanese, Chinese and so on) in the table!

Comment: What about table and field character set?

Comment: latin1_swedish_ci is collation index, but still, it's wrong... it should be utf8 and utf8_general_ci

Comment: See answer below for links and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, based on your comments, you have invalid character set and collation on your table / columns, so you will need to perform character set conversion and possibly repopulation of the table itself...

`ALTER TABLE [table] MODIFY [column] [type] CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`
`ALTER TABLE [table] DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

Check these links:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html

Comment: I've typed out `ALTER TABLE language MODIFY native_name varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; 
ALTER TABLE native_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` but get the error message: `#1146 - Table 'kite.native_name' doesn't exist`

Comment: Those two commands weren't in succession, you don't NEED to execute both of them. First is an example of field charset change and the second of table charset change... Yet, you've provided field name (native_name) instead of table name (language) to the second query.